# What is it meant by a "hybrid argument"?

Tags: provable-security, terminology, distinguisher

Can anyone explain (or point to a reference for) what a hybrid argument is in a security proof, and when it's convenient or preferable to use it?

Among some of the places where I've seen it mentioned, there is the paper [Boneh, Sahai, Waters - Functional Encryption: Definitions and Challenges](http://link.springer.com/chapter/10.1007%2F978-3-642-19571-6_16). The term *standard hybrid argument* is mentioned in the proof sketch of Theorem 1 within section 4.1.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Quoting from ["On beating the hybrid argument"](http://www.ccs.neu.edu/home/viola/papers/hybrid.pdf) (by Bill Fefferman, Ronen Shaltiel, Christopher Umans and Emanuele Viola; 2012):

> The hybrid argument allows one to relate the distinguishability of a distribution (from uniform) to the predictability of individual bits given a prefix. The argument incurs a loss of a factor $k$ equal to the bit-length of the distributions: $\epsilon$-distinguishability implies $\epsilon/k$-predictability.

As you're looking for a more in-deep and more practical explanation of "hybrid argument", I would like to recommend diving into the PDF ["The hybrid argument"](https://web.archive.org/web/20210506221743/https://kodu.ut.ee/%7Epeeter_l/teaching/krprot08s/hybridarg.pdf), which includes a whole bunch of examples to walk through so you can wrap your head around it completely.

Comment: Thanks for your recommendation, although I was looking for some text, rather than some slides without any written explanation. I have found, though, a place where they seem to explain the hybrid argument a bit more in-depth: the book "Foundations of Cryptography: Volume 1, Basic Tools", from Oded Goldreich.